# online gitlab merge "This repository does not have a satellite"

Tags: merge, gitlab

I'm having a branch and I'm trying to confirm a merge request but instead i get the following message:

"This repository does not have a satellite. Please ask an administrator to fix this issue!"

What does this means and how can I fix this?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlabhq/I4Rw0jh_ab4 may be of some use to understand what it is and what it is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's a problem from gitlab. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/318 and related tweet: https://twitter.com/gitlabstatus/status/641217930445881344

Answer (score 5):

look at the information @gitlabstatus twitter.

RT: @gitlabstatus Satellites are being recreated left and right, causing high load on http://gitlab.com . This should even out in a few minutes.(5:31 - 8 sept. 2015)